# How to edit plot_models functions to have `free_x` scales?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, model

I am trying to plot the estimates using plot_models function from `sjPlot` package, but I would like to have free_x for my facets. I tried editing the code in `plot_models` function as `p + facet_grid(~group, scales = "free_x")`, but I get the following error:

```
Error: Column 6 must be named.
Use .name_repair to specify repair.
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

code:

```
library(sjPlot)
data(efc)

# fit three models
fit1 <- lm(barthtot ~ c160age + c12hour + c161sex + c172code, data = efc)
fit2 <- lm(neg_c_7 ~ c160age + c12hour + c161sex + c172code, data = efc)
fit3 <- lm(tot_sc_e ~ c160age + c12hour + c161sex + c172code, data = efc)

mod.plot <-  plot_models(fit1, fit2, fit3, grid = TRUE)
mod.plot
```

Is there a way I could set `scale = free_x` for `mod.plot`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the `sjPlot` package or the `plot_models` function, but it appeared to me as if they hardcoded the x-axis limits (actually the y-axis since they use `coord_flip()`). If you're okay with a warning about overriding scales, you can do the following:

```
library(sjPlot)
data(efc)

# fit three models
fit1 <- lm(barthtot ~ c160age + c12hour + c161sex + c172code, data = efc)
fit2 <- lm(neg_c_7 ~ c160age + c12hour + c161sex + c172code, data = efc)
fit3 <- lm(tot_sc_e ~ c160age + c12hour + c161sex + c172code, data = efc)

mod.plot <-  plot_models(fit1, fit2, fit3, grid = TRUE)

mod.plot + facet_grid(~group, scales = "free_x") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(NA, NA))
mod.plot
```

[image]